# Able to "upvote" comment on a deleted answer

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers

On [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form/8054177#8054177), there is a comment which I am able to click the up arrow (great comment button) on.  The vote registers, as in, it changes the arrow to orange, however when I refresh the page my upvote is not reflected.

Is this desired?  Should there not be a message such as "This comment in on a deleted answer; the comment cannot be voted on"?

Comment: Does it matter? The answer is deleted.

Comment: Does it really matter? The number of people who are going to see that answer is relatively small (10K+ users only) and the number of those who want to up-vote deleted comments is even smaller.

Answer (score 4):

That *used* to trigger an alert saying

> Comments on deleted answers cannot be upvoted

Recent [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), I assume

Comment: I suspect someone at SE corporate is trying to slim down the page a bit. The error message *is* kinda superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

On Meta Stack Overflow, which is using revision 2011.11.8.6 of the code (instead of the revision 2011.11.8.4 used on Stack Overflow), voting a comment on a deleted post doesn't show an error message, and the vote seems accepted.

[image: screenshot]

When you refresh the page, the comment is shown as not voted.

[image: screenshot]

This means the vote was not really recorded, also because (as pointed out from Anna Lear) there should be a 1 close the the black arrow, which is missing in the first screenshot I shown.

It simply happens that the error message is not shown anymore, but the vote is not recorded.

Comment: If it was fully accepted, there would be number "1" beside it. It seems like the voting didn't finish. What happens if you refresh the page?

Comment: That is why I said, "the vote seems accepted." `:-)` The second screenshot shows what happens when I refresh the page.

Comment: Oh, derp. I missed the sentence between the images. :)