# Why is upvoting icon enabled on deleted question comments?

Tags: support, voting, user-interface

As discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111408/able-to-upvote-comment-on-a-deleted-answer), if you try to upvote a comment on a deleted answer, you get an error message:

> Comments on deleted answers cannot be upvoted

Wouldn't it be better, though, if the upvote icon were simply not available in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called *"Just in Time Training."*  By offering the upvote arrow and then providing an error message, you are teaching people how the system works, instead of confusing them by hiding the arrow for mysterious reasons.

Comment: How come it's missing from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered) then?

Comment: That's a historically locked post.  The appearance of the post is significantly altered to give a visual indication that the post is different from the others.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the distinction as far as the above rationale is concerned!

Comment: Well, you basically can't do *anything* on that post.

Comment: You can't do all that much on deleted ones either! The only difference I can perceive is that deleted posts may have their contents edited. You still can't vote, though. I would lean towards not having upvote/downvote icons on deleted posts, either... or, better, visually grey them out and make them non-clickable. I get annoyed when the system pretends it's going to let me snog it, and then spits in my face instead at the last moment.

Answer (score 1):

No. By the option still being there, users have the option of clicking it and finding out that they're not allowed to upvote comments on deleted posts. If you remove it, people just wonder where it went, and may not realize that they can't upvote comments on deleted posts. Then we get questions here on meta "where are the buttons?"